# Exporting data from mysql to hbase

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase

I have an application which is backed by MySQL for storage. 
The data is of the order of few terabytes as of now, and is continually increasing.

**I am wanting to use HBase/Mongo/CAssandra for storage. How can I export my MySQL data to HBase ?**

Currently I am not using any of the Hadoop technologies, and would be peeping in, once I get clear about this process.

Thanks
Jack

Comment: You've tagged the question with MongoDB and Cassandra, but appear to only need to export MySQL into HBase .. is that correct?  Just trying to check you aren't looking for a solution for MySQL into any of the other DBs.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried [Sqoop](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_introduction)? It can [import](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase) from MySQL to HBase.